# I've lost a scalar function in Access 2010 - how do I put it back? (I have the function in SQL)

Tags: function, sql-server-2005, ms-access-2010

I have a form in Access 2010 (.adp, not .accdb) that references a function titled dbo.search which seems to be missing.  I am getting this error:

Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.search", or the name is ambiguous.

I cannot find the function "search" in the navigation pain, so I think I need to add it back.  I have the function in a SQL 2005 database - what do I do?

Comment: Now I'm getting the same error when I try to run a query in SQL that uses the function in question.  I wonder if it's a case-sensitivity issue?

Comment: It WAS a case-sensitivity issue.  I went into SQL, renamed the function "dbo.Search" to "dbo.search" and that fixed everything.  Wow, I was chasing my tail for a while on that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a case-sensitivity issue (hooray for SQL 2005).  I went into SQL, renamed the function "dbo.Search" to "dbo.search" and that fixed everything.  Wow, I was chasing my tail for a while on that one.

Hopefully this helps someone else someday.